# Compile libtorrent examples with command line MSVC 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, libtorrent

I've been lurking stackoverflow for well over a year now and I've finally ran into a problem that I just can't seem to have any luck with. I'm trying to build a simple proof of concept application that uses libtorrent before I try anything complicated. I can get the examples built just fine using bjam and I can get my own simple application (a clone of simple_client.cpp really) to compile and run just fine using a little hack by modifying the bjam file. But I'd prefer to not be anchored down using bjam, so could anyone lend a hand on getting the examples to compile using the MSVC commandline? I've tried variations of the following command

```
cl -D _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D TORRENT_WINDOWS=1 /EHsc /I C:\Libs\boost_1_54_0\      torrenter.cpp /I C:\Libs\libtorrent-rasterbar-0.15.6\include\libtorrent /I C:\Libs\libtorrent-rasterbar-0.15.6\include\ /I C:\Libs\libtorrent-rasterbar-0.15.6\zlib /link /LIBPATH:C:\Libs\boost_1_54_0\lib
```

but I'm met with all kinds of errors like redefined functions and such. I've got a feeling that it has to do with some preprocessor defines that I need to feed into cl but I really have no clue what I need to give it.

I've got boost 1.54.0 installed, libtorrent 0.15.6, and MSVC Express 2012 edition and I'm on window 7 64-bit.

Any help you guys could give would really be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Not sure whether `-D` works when calling cl. Try replacing that with `/D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` (get rid of the space in between). Another way to go about this is to create a project in the IDE, and then see how it's passing the arguments to cl.

Comment: @Praetorian Same output as with -D so I assume -D is valid. Alright, there's more material on building this type of program with the IDE so I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

if you invoke bjam with the additional arguments "-an" it will, instead of building, print out all the command lines it's executing. This may be useful. -a means to rebuild all unconditionally, -n means to print out the command lines instead of executing them.

However, given the limited command line length in the windows shell, it's forced to use response files. This means you won't get a full view of the command line without also opening up one of the .rsp files for the bulk of the arguments.